# ¿Por qué el modelo de conjugación es Sonreír y no Reír?

Tags: verbos, conjugación, asale

Más allá de la respuesta obvia (así lo estableció la ASALE), ¿Por qué el modelo de conjugación es *sonreír* y no *reír*?. Al comparar, con otros modelos de conjugación (prever - ver o deshacer - hacer), el modelo suele ser el verbo más corto. ¿Por qué no fue así con el verbo reír?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con el modelo de conjugación? Porque cada verbo tiene su propio modelo, de hecho en la página de la RAE puedes encontrar el modelo de reír. https://dle.rae.es/re%C3%ADr

Comment: @serfe si miras en la página, se menciona *Conjug. c. sonreír.* y sonreír aparece como *Conjg. modelo*, a diferencia de los otros verbos que menciono (deshacer aparece *Conjug. c. hacer* y prever *Conjug. c.ver*)

Comment: ¿Tal vez porque normalmente reír se usa de manera reflexiva (yo me río)? Es raro decir "yo río", pero lo sé, nunca lo había pensado. Por cierto, si tienes cuenta de Twitter, le puedes preguntar directamente a la RAE. Suelen contestar a la mayoría de preguntas.

Comment: Gracias @Dog_69, dejo la respuesta que me dan en la RAE publicada

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acuerdo con la RAE, el verbo reír no puede ser modelo pues:

> La elección del verbo modelo tiene una justificación ortográfica: ciertas formas del verbo «reír» («rio», «riais») no pueden ser modelos en cuanto a su acentuación gráfica para verbos con esta terminación por ser monosílabos ortográficos que no se tildan.

Es decir, dado que en pretérito *él sonrió* con tilde pero *él rio* sin tilde (con acento en la o), tiene la prioridad el verbo que maneja la tilde

Comment: Tiene sentido, pero entonces no tengo claro por qué *ver* sí que es un modelo...

Comment: @wimi interesante, me sumo a [la conversación de Twitter](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/1321002120443809793) y lo pregunto yo.